# С большой или маленькой буквы пишется слово "интернет"?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

В текстах это слово пишется то так, то так. А как же правильно?

Comment: Печать, радио, телевидение, интернет - средства массовой информации

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если слово "интернет" употреблено как первая часть сложных слов, вроде "интернет-кафе", "интернет-общение", то оно пишется с маленькой буквы и через дефис.
В остальных случаях "интернет" пишется также с маленькой буквы, это слово перестало быть именем собственным.

Comment: Пишется как с маленькой, так и с большой буквы. Оба варианта верны и зафиксированы в словарях.

Answer (score 4):

А вот в словарях и на gramota.ru говорится другое. Есть мнение, что если речь идет о глобальной сети - то с прописной буквы пишем ("нашел в Интернете информацию").
Но: "мобильный интернет", "быстрый интернет" - со строчной.

Так как же правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендация писать Интернет с заглавной содержится в словаре Лопатина и оспаривается очень многими источниками. Думаю, что с окончательной потерей интернетом признаков имени собственного пропадет и заглавная.

Comment: Я думаю, что в словосочетании "сеть Интернет" обязательно написание с заглавной буквы. В сложных словах (интернет-кафе, интернет-доступ, интернет-общение) - однозначно со строчной. В остальных случаях - по контексту.

Comment: Если вы обоснуете, чем это принципиально отличается от "сеть телефидения и радиовещания", я с вами соглашусь.   
Лопатин, насколько понимаю, рассуждал примерно так же, но с ним не согласились.

Comment: По идее, интернет - только одна из сетей. 
> В 1990-е годы Интернет объединил в себе большинство существовавших тогда сетей (хотя некоторые, как Фидонет, остались обособленными).  

Но пользователь вряд ли об этом думает, так что интернет для него - не конкретная сеть (противопоставленная, например, Фидо), а все явление в целом. То есть, скорее, имя нарицательное.

Comment: Да, нечто подобное ("одна из") и говорил Лопатин в известном письме "Грамоте". Возражения не полчили столь широкой известности, поэтому я их воспроизвел: интернет потерял статус имени собственного, перестав быть просто "сетью" и став одним из средств связи и одновременно - видов СМИ. Интернет противопоставляется не всяким ФИДОнетам, которые теперь воспринимаются как часть Интернета, а *интранету* - ситеме внутренней связи.

Answer (score 2):

"Интернет" пишется как с большой, так и с маленькой буквы. Оба варианта верны и равноправны.

С одной стороны, Интернет — это название глобальной информационной сети, следовательно, является именем собственным, поэтому писать его необходимо с большой буквы. С другой — есть мнение, что Интернет уже давно стал настолько распространенным и общепринятым информационным каналом, что превратился из имени собственного в имя нарицательное.
Обе позиции имеют право на существование, а потому оба варианта верны.

Ранее официально утвержденным (в словарях) вариантом было написание с большой буквы. Однако в 4-м издании «Русского орфографического словаря» РАН под редакцией В. В. Лопатина, О. Е. Ивановой, в котором слово «интернет» зафиксировано как с большой, так и с маленькой буквы. 
https://lingvanotes.blogspot.com/2010/03/blog-post.html